# Finding extrema of a function when one of the variables go away after differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Sorry for the long title, I wasn't sure how to explain this exactly.

Let's say I have the following function

$f(x,y) = x^2 + 2y$

I want to find the extrema of this function with respect to $x$ and $y$ to try and minimize it. So normally, I would set the partial derivative of the function wrt each variable and set them to zero.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$

$2x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$

So we can say that $x=0$ minimizes this function.

But what can we say about $y$ exactly?

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2$

$2= 0$ is nonsensical

Perhaps these types of optimization problems are somehow degenerate?

Comment: This simply means this function is always increasing with regards to the $y$ axis. If you are limited to a closed domain then you can use it's boundaries as your extreme points. If not, then you don't have extreme points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{df}{dy}=2$ just means that the derivative is never $0$, so there are no critical points. You can make the function value as small as you want by making $y$ small, so there is no minimum.